# What should a sign-out function look like in order to "reload" the app?

Tags: ios, swift, class, initialization

I'm currently developing an app where the user has to signin on the first launch of the app. The login gets stored so that the user doesn't need to redo that procedure every time he opens the app after a termination.

I'm currently trying to implement a signout button which deletes the stored login data and preferences and **should "reload" the app** and show the login view again, **just as if the user would have never opened the app in the first place** (the same effect you see in apps like Spotify).

I already managed to program the first part, though, I really struggle with the second one.

My first approach to that problem was shifting UI- and Variable-related code into a seperate function which is being called in the viewDidLoad() and registering that function as a NotificationCenter Key to be called on all already initialized classes on signout via a NotificationCenter post by the class that triggers the signout.

That approach kinda worked. The problem is that a lot of other Notification Center posts get called many times which results in the app not working properly until termination and restart.

I really can't find a reason for that behaviour. Though, I really think that this, even if it works, is not a proper way to achieve that since I "reload" (in the sense of that function) all classes and not only the visible ones, which should be very inefficient on a long term.

---

**How would you approach that problem?** 
I don't think I am the only one struggling with this. 
**Do you know how "popular" apps achieve that effect?**

PS: Is there a way to "deinit" a class of type ViewController? If there is maybe that would be an approach to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you shouldn't rely on Notification Center when implementing such behaviour. If you want to replace all ViewControllers in memory with a single one (eg. login screen), you should replace the `rootViewController` of your app's `window`. You can do it by simply setting the property:

```
class YourViewController {
    static func presentOn(window: UIWindow) {
        let vc = YourViewController.init(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: Bundle.main) // or however you want to initialize it
        window.rootViewController = vc
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

then call `YourViewController.presentOn(UIApplication.shared.windows.first!)`

Or if you want to have animation, use a custom segue subclass, in which you override the `perform` method with your custom animation (for example using [snapshot views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview)).

```
class PresentAsRootSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!
        destination.view.frame = window.bounds
        let snapshot: UIView = destinationView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            //do your animations here
        }, completion: { _ in
            window.rootViewController = destination
            window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal
            source.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

then in your logout ViewController call `PresentAsRootSegue(source: self, destination: LoginViewController()).perform()`

If after the change the old ViewControllers are still in memory, then it means you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What should I use as nibName? I couldn't find anything on the web what the name is supposed to be. I use storyboards

Comment: If you use storyboards then use 
`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)`
then
`let viewController = 
storyboard.instantiateViewController("YourViewController") as?
YourViewController`
Remember to add "Storyboard ID" name in the Interface Builder. Or use [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen) for easier instantiating.

Comment: This calls the onboarding now: `let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDLaunchViewController")` `UIApplication.shared.windows.firs‌​t!.rootViewControlle‌​r = vc` `UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.makeKeyAndVisible()`And it works! I also cleaned my code a bit now utilizing viewWillAppear(), viewDidAppear(), and viewDidDisappear() for var-related stuff, registering Notfication Center Observers, and removing Notification Center Observers.